# Read value from DOM json

Tags: jquery, json, magento2

When i do Ctrl+U, there is below json in my page DOM

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
  "#country": {
    "regionUpdater": {
      "optionalRegionAllowed": true,
      "regionListId": "#region_id",
      "regionInputId": "#region",
      "postcodeId": "#zip",
      "form": "#form-validate",
      "regionJson": {
        "config": {
          "show_all_regions": true,
          "regions_required": [
            "AU",
            "BR",
            "CA",
            "CN",
            "CO",
            "HR",
            "EE",
            "IN",
            "LV",
            "LT",
            "MX",
            "PL",
            "RO",
            "ES",
            "CH",
            "US"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to get regionJson value in my custom js file, Can someone please give me any solution or any idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get regionJson like this,

```
json = {
  "country": {
    "regionUpdater": {
      "optionalRegionAllowed": true,
      "regionListId": "#region_id",
      "regionInputId": "#region",
      "postcodeId": "#zip",
      "form": "#form-validate",
      "regionJson": {
        "config": {
          "show_all_regions": true,
          "regions_required": [
            "AU",
            "BR",
            "CA",
            "CN",
            "CO",
            "HR",
            "EE",
            "IN",
            "LV",
            "LT",
            "MX",
            "PL",
            "RO",
            "ES",
            "CH",
            "US"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(json["#country"]["regionUpdater"]["regionJson"])
```

Comment: but i can't change json format like i can't remove #country from json key

Comment: You can get like this `console.log(json["#country"]["regionUpdater"]["regionJson"])`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, ideally # is not valid in json key name.

So i used replace method to remove it, then parse it

```
 var getTxt=$('#script').html().replace('#country','country');
 var jsonData= JSON.parse(getTxt);
  
 console.log(jsonData.country.regionUpdater.regionJson);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ujry3n5c/)**

Answer (score 0):

Batter Solution would be to find the `phtml` file which call might be calling block or function which are providing the `regionJson` data and you can get the same data in your js file by invoking it using `text/x-magento-init` and pass config same as passed in your question you can also store that in the javascript global `window` object and get this value later in the js file.